# How can I generate a receipt for POS?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to create a sales app. One of the feature is to generate the receipt for POS. I think I have to create the file first, but I would like to know what's the simplest and fastest way to do it for Android. Is there a library to generate receipts already? Thank you in advance.

Comment: by "generate", do you mean generate template? or just print/send data to pos printer?

Comment: if you want sample program in android. go find some sample program in github. you can't find any sample program here. unless you make your own program then ask something regards to your code.

Comment: @AlvinTom I need to create an app that creates a receipt of shopping list. After that, I want to send it via email or print it via POS. The problem is, I don't know how to write a receipt or take a previous template and write on it. I already investigated, but I can't find a good example.